# BigBlueButton error - error 500 after setting TURN server

Tags: bigbluebutton

It was fine until I installed the turn server to enable WebRTC
Its a google cloud server, under Firefall but I open the ports and test with netcat, just like the tutorial says.

Potential problems described below:

```
# IP does not match:
#                           IP from ifconfig: 10.142.0.2
#   /etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton: live.MYSITE.com
# Warning: API URL IPs do not match host:
#
#                                IP from ifconfig: 10.142.0.2
#  /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo/bbb_api_conf.jsp: live.MYSITE.com

# Not running:  LibreOffice
....................
# Error: Could not connect to the configured hostname/IP address
#
#    https://live.MYSITE.com/
#
# If your BigBlueButton server is behind a firewall, see FAQ.

# Warning: The setting of EXTERNAL-IP for proxy_pass in
#
#    /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/sip.nginx
#
# does not match the local IP address (10.142.0.2).
# (This is OK if you've manually changed the values)

# Warning: The API demos are installed and accessible from:
#
#    https://live.MYSITE.com/demo/demo1.jsp
#
# These API demos allow anyone to access your server without authentication
# to create/manage meetings and recordings. They are for testing purposes only.
# If you are running a production system, remove them by running:
#
#    sudo apt-get purge bbb-demo
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the product manager for BigBlueButton.  I think you've already asked this question in our GitHub account and we're responding there

https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/issues/6459

Rather than have us respond in two places, let's continue the discussion at the above link.